# Linker operation in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, linker, emu8086

I have read in the text book of assembly language that the linker will determine the program's entry point. For example, the typical linker output is

```
START       STOP          LENGTH        NAME        CLASS
00000H      0003FH        0040H         mystack     STACK
00040H      00045H        0006H         mydata      DATA
00050H      00063H        0014H         mycode      CODE

program entry point at   0005:0000
```

How linker determine the entry point. If that is hard coded in the binary file, the loader may see that another program is started from 0005:0000.

Any thought?

Comment: The linker will generate a DOS EXE file that has fixup locations encoded at the beginning of the executable. When the DOS EXE loader load the executable it looks through the fixup table to find the memory locations that need to be adjusted. The adjustment involves adding the the base segment address where the program is actually loaded in memory with the segment stored in the executable. 0005h will in effect have its value modified.

Comment: So that is the confirmation on linker won't exactly know the starting point of the program and that is the duty of the loader. Just wanted to know why that report such a thing. Thanks.

Comment: @mahmood The linker knows where the entry point is relative to the beginning of the program image.  It knows that because it declared some symbol to refer to the entry point.

Comment: @fuz: So, why isn't that 0000:0000? Why linker start that from 0005:0000?

Comment: @mahmood I have no idea why this is the entry point.  Could be whatever reason.  It is not terribly uncommon that the entry point is not the first address in the image.

Comment: could it be that - ahead of the CODE segment - you defined a stack of 64 bytes ( 0000:0000 to 0000:003f == 0003:000f ) and some data ( 0004:0000 to 0004:0005)? the next free segment then is 5